# C++ Qt QTableWidget item moves when resizing column

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am writing a C++ plugin for an existing application where I need to display a window which contains a QTableWidget using Qt.

Here is an excerpt of my working code where I am building the QTableWidget and filling the cells.

```
tableWidget->setRowCount(0);  // clear tablewidget
tableWidget->clearContents();

tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);  
tableWidget->setRowCount(2);  

QStringList header;
header << "Date" << "Owner" << "Type" << "Folder" << "Path";
tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(20);  
tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header);

tableWidget->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("dog")));
tableWidget->setItem(0,1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("cat")));
tableWidget->setItem(0,2,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("frog")));
tableWidget->setItem(1,0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString("shark")));

tableWidget->item(0,0)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
tableWidget->item(0,1)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
tableWidget->item(0,2)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

It works as expected, except the data inside each successive column is moved further right than the previous column.  This can be exaggerated when you resize a column and see the data in columns to the right "slide" even further right.

Here are 2 screenshots of the effect (before and after column resize).  You can see how the words "cat" and "frog" have moved more to the right than normal.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  I want each cells text to be aligned to the left of each column.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem appears to be related to Windows Display settings.
My laptop text display setting was set to "Medium - 125%".
When I set it back to "Smaller - 100%" then the problem went away.

I would still like my program to work properly if the user should use 125% text, but at least now I know the cause.

Does anyone know how I to prevent the above problem when using 125% text?

[image]